# What is the difference difference between AwsS3 and Amazon S3 (amazon_s3) for KnpGaugretteBundle?

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use Gaufrette and S3 in my Symfony project and it doesn't work. I got the error:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AmazonS3' not found in /var/www/headoo/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 514

So I guessed that maybe I am using the wrong version of the adapter. But I don't understand what is the difference between AwsS3 and Amazon S3. The doc seems a little short for those who are starting with S3.

I use one of the latest versions of aws-sdk-php which is 3.2.*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this set of bundles in latest symfony and it works great:

```
    "knplabs/gaufrette":                    "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle":         "dev-master",
    "amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php": "dev-master",
    "cybernox/amazon-webservices-bundle": "dev-master",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~2.7@dev"
```

Comment: Thanks @shacarsol, but why do you use both amazon-webservices-bundle and aws-sdk-php? It seems that the first one is deprecated. And which adapter do you use? Because on the KnpGaufretteBundle doc there are two (AwsS3 and Amazon S3) https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle

Comment: I'm using  Gaufrette\Adapter\AmazonS3 adapter, this are the dependecies of   "knplabs/gaufrette",  i didn't added them myself. but works for me fine in two projects